# not able to use setChannelId in android 5.0 and above

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

i am trying to setup a setChannelId and adding an action in notification itself to stop sync data

following is my code

```
        return new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "STOP SYNC", stopServiceIntent)
                .setChannelId(SHEALTH_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(r.getString(R.string.shealth_notification_title))
                .setContentText(r.getString(R.string.shealth_notification_text))
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .build();
```

The error that i am getting is

> cannot resolve method "setChannelId"

If i change my code use use `Notification` only instead of `NotificationCompat`, then i do get following error

> Call requires API Level 26 ( current is min 21)

```
 return new android.support.v7.app.Notification.Builder(context)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "STOP SYNC", stopServiceIntent)
                    .setChannelId(SHEALTH_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(r.getString(R.string.shealth_notification_title))
                    .setContentText(r.getString(R.string.shealth_notification_text))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .build();
```

but i want to allow my app to run on Android 5.0 and above hence i can't set min sdk to API level 26

Following are my settings related to sdk in build.gradle

1. minSdkVersion 21
2. targetSdkVersion 28

i am not show how will i able to write such code which support 5.0 and above with channel id

Comment: Channel ID is **not mandatory** to specify for API **below 26**. So, no need to worry. Just follow the same, it'll work as it should. Refer to the doc of [NotificationChannel](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no need to set ChannelId for versions below 26 API ( Android O ). You can check your version at runtime if you want to support both cases.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    return new android.support.v7.app.Notification.Builder(context)
                            .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "STOP SYNC", stopServiceIntent)
                            .setChannelId(SHEALTH_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                            .setContentTitle(r.getString(R.string.shealth_notification_title))
                            .setContentText(r.getString(R.string.shealth_notification_text))
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .build();
                }
                else {
                    return new android.support.v7.app.Notification.Builder(context)
                            .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "STOP SYNC", stopServiceIntent)
                            .setContentTitle(r.getString(R.string.shealth_notification_title))
                            .setContentText(r.getString(R.string.shealth_notification_text))
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .build();
                }
```

Or You can use `NotificationCompat` class from support lib to support older versions without checking version yourself.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(context, SHEALTH_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
```

Comment: there is no `android.support.v7.app.Notification.Builder` exists it should be `android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompact.Builder`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, worked fine for me.

```
public void showNotification() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int notificationId = 1;
    String channelId = "channel-01";
    String channelName = "Channel Name";
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, importance);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Test Notofication")
            .setContentText("Testing Okay");

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NotificationCompat` class to build your notification if you are supporting older Android versions:

```
return new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, SHEALTH_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
    // set every other field
```

This compat class will add the notification channel for Oreo devices and above, and ignore it for Nougat and below.